# php read and updating value on file from another file

Tags: php, file, fopen, fgets

I have 2 files (A.vcf and ref1.vcf) 
A.vcf like this:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
1   5   .   A   C   222 .   INDEL;IS=6,0.111111;DP=54;VDB=1.384012e-01;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=2,3,1,4;MQ=32;FQ=10.8;PV4=1,0.38,0.00012,0.00052   GT:PL:GQ    0/1:45,0,147:47
2   7   .   G   T   222 .   DP=106;VDB=1.997151e-13;RPB=-2.402409e+00;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=1,1,44,58;MQ=20;FQ=-275;PV4=1,1,0.0029,1  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,248,0:99
3   15  .   A   G   222 .   DP=106;VDB=2.982598e-04;RPB=-2.402409e+00;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=1,1,44,58;MQ=20;FQ=-266;PV4=1,1,0.003,1   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,239,0:99
4   11  .   T   A   222 .   DP=85;VDB=3.949915e-01;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,29,44;MQ=22;FQ=-247  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,220,0:99
```

ref1.vcf :

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT
1   5   ref12345    A   C
2   15  ref45673    A   G
3   25  ref67893    C   T
4   35  ref66663    C   A
```

I want to change the heading of the file that corresponds to the reference A.vcf ref1.vcf. 
thus, this initially:

```
id = .
ref = A
alt = C
qual = 222
```

I want to be like this:

```
id = ref12345
ref = A
alt = C
qual = 222
```

but no change happens.
whether there was a mistake with my code?

```
<?php
    $dataSNP = "A.vcf";
    $handleSNP = fopen($dataSNP, "r");
        if ($handleSNP)
        {
            while (($lineSNP = fgets($handleSNP, 4096)) !== false)
            {
                $lineSNP = explode("\t", $lineSNP);
                //removing first with '#'
                if (!empty($lineSNP[0][0]) && $lineSNP[0][0] != '#')
                {
                    $new_dataSNP[] = $lineSNP;
                }
            }
            if (!feof($handleSNP))
            {
                echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
            fclose($handleSNP);
        }
        //update 'pos', but not working
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($new_dataSNP); $i++)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print("chrom = ".$new_dataSNP[$i][0]. "\n");
            print("position = ".$new_dataSNP[$i][1]. "\n");
            $file = "ref1.vcf";

            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            if ($handle)
            {
                while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false)
                {
                    $line = explode("\t", $line);

                    if(($line[1] == $new_dataSNP[$i][1]) && ($line[3] == $new_dataSNP[$i][3]) && ($line[4] == $new_dataSNP[$i][4]))
                    {
                        $new_dataSNP[$i][2] = $line[2];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!feof($handle))
                {
                    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
                }
                fclose($handle);
            } 


                print("id = ".$new_dataSNP[$i][2]. "\n");
                print("ref = ".$new_dataSNP[$i][3]. "\n");
                print("alt = ".$new_dataSNP[$i][4]. "\n");

        }
?>
```

This code is simple, but I am confused to find faults. is there anything that can help me?

Comment: Do you really have tabs in your files? In your data posted here, there are only spaces.

Comment: yes, i use "tabs", not "spaces". can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: `fgets` does not cut off the new-line character `\n` at the end of each line. So, `$line[4]` contains the new-line character, while `$new_dataSNP[$i][4]` does not.

Replace

```
$line = explode("\t", $line);
```

with

```
$line = explode("\t", trim($line));
```

Comment: but, why if I use a large file deng many 2000 lines still can not update? for the case of small files or 10 line, still resolved. why like it? is there any other solution?

Comment: Do I get you right, that it work's now for not-too-large files? It may be a memory issue, since you read the whole file into an array.